# Twilio Child Call Status incorrect?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twilio

I'm experimenting with Twilio and I'm confused a bit by the ultimate status of my calls.

Here's what I'm doing. I'm making a call to a Twilio Phone Number which is hooked into an application endpoint. The app makes a database record of the call and then uses Twiml to make a secondary call out to another phone. After the call is complete, the call record is updated with data retrieved from Twilio then a secondary call record is created from the call in my account where its parent_call_sid is my original call's sid.

My issue is, if I call the Twilio Number but let the Twiml Dial timeout, the child call status ends up being 'completed' instead of 'no-answer'.

My question is why is this happening? Do I need to configure how I dial out differently in order to receive the appropriate status for my calls?

> UPDATE:
>   This has been resolved. The issue was voicemail picking up before Twilio's default timeout of 30 seconds ended the call, resulting in a 'completed' status. By reducing the timeout Twilio was able to end the call with 'no-answer' before the voice mail picked up.

Comment: Can you share the code you are using to dial out and receive these statuses? I'm not sure what you could do differently if I don't know what you did in the first place.

Comment: This has been resolved. The issue was the timeout was long enough for the voice mail to pick up, which does not count as 'no-answer'. Reducing the timeout so that Twilio ends the call before voice mail answers correctly results in a 'no-answer' status.

Comment: Ah, good to hear it is resolved. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was the timeout was long enough for the voice mail to pick up, which does not count as `no-answer`. Reducing the [`Timeout`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/voice/making-calls#optional-parameters) so that Twilio ends the call before voice mail answers correctly results in a `no-answer` status.